# Meteor with dynamic select2 data like in typeahead

Tags: meteor, jquery-select2

I am searching for a solution how to dynamically add data to select2 in meteor. 
I want to refresh data in select2 after user types string in select2 input box (filtering). Similar like typeahead package is doing for input field with server method to query data.

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in the https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete package. It's not really possible to make array-based libraries such as select2 or typeahead completely reactive on data, which is what that does.

Comment: I checked autocomplete also, but I would like to have a limitation to select from existing docs only and when user selects a document from collection I need also the _id of the document to unique identify the doc.

Comment: autocomplete has a callback to determine when an item is selected. You can use this to update the current selection, so that something valid is always selected. Anyway, up to you.

Comment: I would then also try to add _id value on selection. Maybe on data attribute. Has anyone some sample code?